Multiple jars and how jpackage deploys them
I have a Java application (with a main()).
I use "-classpath .:./jars/*" in order to use a license manager jar and a database server jar, both in the "jars" subdirectory.
It compiles and runs OK.
Now I want to deploy it to users.
I put the two specific jars into the "deploy" subdirectory along with "foo.jar" (which contains the main()), then I use jpackage:
jpackage \
    --input       deploy \
    --main-jar    "foo.jar" \
    --type        dmg

jpackage (on MacOS) makes a .dmg file. When I double-click the .dmg and copy the app to the Applications folder, I get:
$ ls
foo.cfg     license4j-runtime-library.jar   postgresql-42.7.3.jar
foo.jar
$ cat foo.cfg
[Application]
app.mainjar=$APPDIR/foo.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR/license4j-runtime-library.jar
app.classpath=$APPDIR/postgresql-42.7.3.jar

[JavaOptions]
java-options=-Djpackage.app-version=1.0

When I double-click on the app's icon, it appears to start (I can see the name of the main class in the title bar), but then it stops. There is no error message. It just doesn't work.
I'm wondering if the two "app.classpath=" lines are correct. Perhaps they should be one?
If so, what is the correct syntax?
I also need to solve this problem for Windows when jpackage makes a ".msi" file.
Any thoughts?
Thank you!
I expected the program to launch completely, but after a few seconds, with no output, it stops.

I can assure you the multiple lines is good to use. All my .cfg files look similar and the applications run.
